# Find the partition function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

> Consider $N$ particles in a volume $V$ at temperature $T$. Given the Hamiltonian
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(p_{x,i}+\frac{q}{2}y_i B)^2+(p_{y,i}-\frac{q}{2}x_i B)^2+p_{z,i}^2}{2m}$$
>   find the partition function $Z$.

My problem is that I’m facing an integral in $dxdydzdp_x dp_y dp_z$ of the function $e^{\frac{-\beta}{2m}(p_{x,i}+\frac{q}{2}y_i B)^2}$. And I don't know what to do, if I integrate with respect $p_x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ I get something independent of $y$ and $B$ which seems odd.

Comment: You are being sloppy in the integration. For a clearer picture, try using the coordinate transformation : $p'_x = p_x +q/2yB$,  $p'_y = p_y - q/2xB$, and then integrate. The partition function won't be independent of $B$.

Comment: I still get the integral of $e^{\frac{-\beta}{2m}(p'_x)^2 dp'_x}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. And that's just $(\frac{2\pi m}{\beta})^{1/2}$

Comment: This seems to be a primitive version of the [van Leeuwen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr–van_Leeuwen_theorem).